# Create New List From Existing Lists Comparison

Tags: c#, linq, list, join

I have two lists:

```
List<Course> studentCourses = Course.GetCourses(student.PIDM, GetTermCode());  
List<OfferedCourse> offeredCourses = OfferedCourse.GetOfferedCourses();
```

studentCourses have the properties `SubjectCode` and `CourseNumber`.
offeredCourses also have the properties `SubjectCode` and `CourseNumber`.

I want to create a third list of type `List<Course>` that contains only items from `studentCourses` that match both the `SubjectCode` and `CourseNumber` of an item in `offeredCourses`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post what you have already attempted?

Comment: Well, what is stopping you?

Comment: Just add the 2nd ? `oc => oc.SubjectCode == sc.SubjectCode && oc.CourseNumber == sc.CourseNumber)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ended up being:

```
IEnumerable<Course> courses = studentCourses.Where(sc => offeredCourses.Any(oc => oc.SubjectCode == sc.SubjectCode && oc.CourseNumber == sc.CourseNumber));
```

A big thank you to cosmo0 who pointed me in the right direction and Magnus who double checked my work!

Comment: no worries op, glad i can help with your "question". it happens to all of us. & i was actually trying to help you :)

Comment: If my answer didn't solve your problem, it shouldn't be accepted. If you still can, please un-mark it and wait 2 days to mark yours. If I helped you, you can just upvote my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Linq uses a non-intuitive syntax for that: use `Contains` from the collection that might contain the values you're after.

```
var result = studentCourses.Where(c => offeredCourses.Contains(o => o.SubjectCode == c.SubjectCode && o.CourseNumber == c.CourseNumber));
```

Comment: The portion: offeredCourses.Contains(o => o.SubjectCode is erroring out.  It is not viewing o as an OfferedCourse object so no properties are available to select from.  Any idea why this might be?